# Single camera view for multiple views

Tags: iphone, ios, view, camera, image

I currently have an app that uses many views. Each views uses a camera view. User of the app can select certain items in one view and that item will show in the camera view. Basically, they can use that item to edit their picture.

My problem is that, there's too many camera view and it takes up too many space/memory. And I want to use only ONE camera view for my whole app. So that takes me to my question...

When user taps on an item inside one of my view. What's the proper way of showing that item he/she tapped on the camera view.

I'm sorry if this is too confusing...

Comment: What platform/OS are you working in? It is impossible to tell from your question.

Comment: Apologize, I am working on iOS iPhone platform.

Answer (score 0):

Have one controller class which a pointer to the camera view and your selected item. You could write a method `setItem:`, which would override the default setter for an `@property UIView *item`. In your implementation of that method, `[cameraView addSubview:item]` should add the named item as an overlay on the camera view, if that's what you want. To remove it use `[item removeFromSuperview]` (do this every time, since even when `item` is `nil` it will still execute properly, it just won't do anything).

Code for the above:

---

Controller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain, setter = setItem:) UIView *item;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *cameraView;
```

---

Controller.m

```
@synthesize item, cameraView;    

- (void)setItem:(UIView *)newItem
{
    [item removeFromSuperview];
    [item release];
    [newItem retain];
    item = newItem;
    [cameraView addSubview:item];
}
```